# DataTables, es6 arrow functions and this

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, datatables, arrow-functions

I have the following [datatables](https://datatables.net/) initialisation in which I use the `preDrawCallback` function to hide and show pagination and filters based on the number of records in the table.

As it is part of a webpack project, I have turned it into es6 but I have had to disable the object shorthand for the function as I am unable to find a way of getting the current table without using `this`:

```js
$tables.DataTable({
  preDrawCallback: function(settings) { // eslint-disable-line object-shorthand

    const $table = $(this); // is there a way to get this table without using this?
    
    // rest of code
  }
})
```

Having looked through a lot of documentation, there doesn't seem to be an argument they pass into the function where I can get that table and all the examples use `$(this)`.

My question is do I have to use this or is there some other way of getting the table so I can change the named function into an arrow function?

**Update**

Seems that I was looking at the wrong problem and didn't need to use arrow functions after all and fixing the lint error solved the need to not use `this` (see answer below), but just in case anyone doesn't want to use `this`, after a lot of console logging of different things, I found the current table id is held in the settings that is passed in so you can do

```
$(`#${settings.sTableId}`).DataTable();
```

Comment: But you could easily use an arrow function and get the table instance.  The only reason for needing `this` would be to work with the api, i.e `this.api()` which is equal to `$(settings.oInstance.init().selector).DataTable()` ...

Comment: Ah right I got the api using: `new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings);` but couldn't see any way of getting the table from that api - that's what confused me as the api had a `.table()` - didn't realise the settings actually held a load of info on the current table too

Comment: `preDrawCallback:(settings) => {  const $table = $(settings.oInstance.init().selector).DataTable()  }   `

Comment: ah, that's how you use it!  Wouldn't that be creating a new instance of all datatables though if it is using the selector - I have multiple datatables on the same page that are initialised with the selector which is a class

Comment: Yes, guessed you have multiple tables since you were in doubt how to pick the right one :)  `$(settings.oInstance.init().selector).DataTable()` (notice, `DataTable()` without params) just return the API instance for the `#table` in question (if it exists) `dataTable()` will return the jQuery instance (if it exists)

Comment: Ah right, just tested it and it is undefined

Comment: See this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/v48gcn9r/**

Comment: Ah yes that only works if there is one table - see this: http://jsfiddle.net/v48gcn9r/1/

Comment: I stand corrected! `$('#'+settings.sTableId).DataTable()` should be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, as you say, the value isn't passed in as a parameter, then you'll need to use a normal function. Normal functions and arrow functions have different behaviors for `this`, so you'll need to pick the right tool for the job.

As for that lint error you're seeing, that doesn't have anything to do with arrow functions. It's just telling you to write it like this:

```
$tables.DataTable({
  preDrawCallback(settings) { // <-- using shorthand on this line
    const $table = $(this); 

    // rest of code
  }
});
```

Comment: Ah I wondered why the error wasn't a use arrow functions error, never knew you could do the callbacks like that, excellent. Thanks!